# Clarity UI Sub Navigation

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm using the below code for the sub navigation in app.component.html, however after selecting a [subnav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3z1Z.jpg) link which does go to next page the selection does not stay highlighted, just the home TAB. What am I missing?

```
> <nav class="subnav">
```

> ```
>   <ul class="nav">
>     <li class="nav-item">
>       <a class="nav-link active" href="/home">Home</a>
>     <li class="nav-item">
>       <a class="nav-link" href="/dashboards">Dashboards</a>
>     </li>
>     <li class="nav-item">
>       <a class="nav-link" href="/tools">Tools</a>
>     </li>
>     <li class="nav-item">
>       <a class="nav-link" href="/faqs">FAQs</a>
>     </li>
>     <li class="nav-item">
>       <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
>     </li>
>   </ul>
> </nav>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

if you're using Angular router you have to put

```
routerLinkActive="active"
```

in each link

Check [here](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/vertical-nav/basic-structure/charmander#examples)

Comment: thanks but thats for the vertical nav, I'm using subnav , see here bottom of the page , routerLinkActive is not mentioned. https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/header#examples

Comment: well, routerLinkActive is valid wherever you user Angular Router Links

Answer (score 2):

The `active` class, which is hard coded in your sample to only be on the Home link. Since it is Angular, you should adapt the anchor tags like you would for any Angular links. It should be something like this if you use Angular with the subnav.

```
<nav class="subnav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/dashboards" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboards</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/tools" routerLinkActive="active">Tools</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/faqs" routerLinkActive="active">FAQs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Spot on Jeremy, thanks, had the syntax slightly incorrect!